# Dragging the imageview by means of touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, touches

My App deals with an imageview and I want to drag the image all over the view by means of touches.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ // This gets you starting position of 
    UITouch *touch = [ [ event allTouches ] anyObject ] ;   

    float touchXBeginPoint = [ touch locationInView:touch.view ].x ;
    float touchYBeginPoint = [ touch locationInView:touch.view ].y ;

    // Calculate the offset between the current image center and the touched points.
     touchOffset = hairImage.center.x - touchXBeginPoint;
    touchOffset1=hairImage.center.y-touchYBeginPoint;

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [ [ event allTouches ] anyObject ] ;

    float distanceMoved =( [ touch locationInView:touch.view ].x + touchOffset ) -  hairImage.center.x  ;
    float distanceMoved1=([touch locationInView:touch.view].y+touchOffset)-hairImage.center.y;
    float newX = hairImage.center.x + distanceMoved;//+distanceMoved1 ;
    float newY=hairImage.center.y+distanceMoved1;
    if( newX > 70 && newX < 150 ){ // setting the boundaries
        hairImage.center = CGPointMake(newX, hairImage.center.y) ;}
    if(newY>100 && newY<180){
        hairImage.center=CGPointMake(newY, hairImage.center.x);
    }}
```

This is the code. Here I can move the imageview successfully along X direction, but my target is to move imageview all over the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit more info on your question helps...like what you have tried, where you got stuck etc..Anyway I just copy pasted the question of your title and googled..Here is the first result

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/